# Why Scanner Object Use Different Locale Other Than Default Locale?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, locale, string-formatting

When I use `nextDouble()` method of Scanner class like

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get("input.txt")))
{
    double d = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.printf(Locale.getDefault(),"%.2f",d);
}
catch (NoSuchElementException | IllegalStateException | IOException e)
{
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`nextDouble()` method get comma seperated strings(like 5,12) but `printf()` method print point seperated number(like 5.12). This difference seems bacause of using different Locale values.
Why nextDouble() and printf() method use different default Locale values?

Comment: What is the locale being used by your `Scanner`?  If it were a US locale, then the comma in `5,12` would not be treated like a decimal point.

Comment: `Locale input = new Scanner(Paths.get("input.txt")).locale();
System.out.println(input);` print tr_TR

Comment: Can you also tell us what `Locale.getDefault()` is?

Comment: This default is en_US.

Comment: You just answered your own question.  But maybe someone can shed light about _why_ this is the default.

Comment: Another interesting thing is when I tried this code with `Scanner input = new Scanner(Paths.get("input.txt")).useLocale(new Locale("tr_TR"))` I got an inputmismatch exception (for comma separated number).